# how to print header http content to string cURL c++

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, curl, java-native-interface

Now im use curl c++ to download file in my server. if using command line to send request im also print the header content to console screen. now i want print the header content to string  or file.txt to see that before go to downloading body content, but impossile. Im also search and do like [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html) but header is empty.
this is my simple code

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream) {
size_t written;
written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
//LOGI("SDK: WRITE DATA");
return written;
}

void downloadFile(std::string url, std::string savepath) {
const char* url_down = url.c_str();

std::string name = "download.apk";
std::string save_path = savepath + "/" + name;

std::string header_path=savepath+"/header.txt";

const char* save_header_down=header_path.c_str();
const char* save_path_down = save_path.c_str();

CURL *curl;
FILE* fp;
FILE* headf;
std::string bufRead;
CURLcode res;
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(save_path_down, "wb");
    headf=fopen(save_header_down,"wb");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url_down);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,headf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,&bufRead);


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, S_Progress);
    startTime = get_timestamp();

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res == CURLE_OK) {
        LOGI("SDK: FILE DOWNLOADED!");
    } else {
        LOGI("SDK:TRANFER FAILED!");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(headf);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    LOGI("SDK:HEADER:%s",bufRead.c_str());
   }

}
```

After run program use method downloadFile, string bufRead is allway empty and im try open header.txt but file not have any content, all is empty. Any one can help me how to show content header http request to string or txt file. Thanks!

Comment: You set `CURLOPT_HEADERDATA` twice. Should one of those be `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`?

Comment: @Galik CURLOPT_HEADERDATA one for print data to header.txt and one send to string bufRead

Comment: CURL doesn't accept `std::string` it only accepts a `FILE*` unless you use a callback function.

Comment: Thanks @Galik i have been solve my problem by using this [link](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinfo.html). by the way, in want modifed header, and add it to download. you can show me what method to used